# RedirectToRoutePermanent doesn't accept Action as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'd like to do this:

```
return RedirectToRoutePermanent("Dealers", new { action = "Join" });
```

but instead I had to do this to make it work:

```
return RedirectPermanent("/dealers/join");
```

Join is an action in the Dealers controller, and another route works fine with being routed to the Dealers controller. But when I try things this way, it errors with no route found. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
return RedirectToActionPermanent("Join", "Dealers");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the MSDN reference, the [ReidrectToRoutePermanent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784429.aspx)  takes a string parameter which should be the route name and not controller name. If you rely on the default route to navigate to /dealers/join then this will not work.  What does your routing table look like? Can you attach the Register Routes code?  Furthermore, I think you want a method [RedirectToActionPermanent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg453883(v=vs.98).aspx) if you're executing within Controller action method scope.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way but can you just include Url.Action() to your method in the call?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedirectToRoutePermanent.
RedirectToRoutePermanent method works with RouteName.
So, you need to pass your RouteName as first parameter and Route parameters as second parameter.

Also, you need to mention controller name as well.
Something like,

```
return RedirectToRoutePermanent("YourRouteName", new { controller="Dealers", action = "Join" });
```

Hope helps.